# How to install Python3 bindings for glib in Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, ubuntu-12.04, glib, cairo

I am using Python3 on an Ubuntu 12.04 system, and I am writing some small apps to teach myself about using cairo from within Python. In idle3 I find the following:

```
    >>> import glib
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import glib
    ImportError: No module named glib
```

I have used Gtk and cairo on the same setup, and python3-gi and python3-gi-cairo are both installed, and in other respects seem to be working fine. It seems there is something else that is missing, but in spite of several web searches I have not unearthed any clues as to what is wrong here.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question is perhaps better suited for [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)?

Comment: Although I specified 'Ubuntu' in the tags, I have no reason to believe this particular question is necessarily confined to Ubuntu. Hence I asked it here. See also my preferred answer, which does not seem to be unique to Ubuntu. (I can't test this because I do not have a Windows box to hand...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For gobject introspection, which is what python3-gi gives you, the proper incantation is this:

```
 >>> from gi.repository import GLib
```

For Cairo, use `cairo` instead of `GLib`.

In general, at least under Linux, the installed gobject introspection typelibs are installed in `/usr/lib/girepository-1.0` (or similar).  The name you use to import is derived straightforwardly from the typelib file name.

Comment: Thanks ergosys, this does indeed solve my problem. I think the code example I was looking at must have been using an earlier version of the binding libraries, hence my confusion.